# How can macro output double quotes

Tags: c, macros, nested

`ATOMIC_JOIN(prefix, detail_platform)` is an macro which will output some string as follows:

> base/atomic/gcc_gnu_x64

in another macro `ATOMIC_DETAIL_HEADER`, which output expected to be:

> "base/atomic/gcc_gnu_x64.hpp"        // notice: double quotes included in the output

I try to write the `ATOMIC_DETAIL_HEADER`, such as：

```
#define ATOMIC_DETAIL_HEADER(prefix) "ATOMIC_JOIN(prefix, ATOMIC_DETAIL_PLATFORM).hpp"

#define ATOMIC_DETAIL_HEADER(prefix) \"ATOMIC_JOIN(prefix, ATOMIC_DETAIL_PLATFORM).hpp\"

#define ATOMIC_DETAIL_HEADER(prefix) "##ATOMIC_JOIN(prefix, ATOMIC_DETAIL_PLATFORM).hpp##"
```

... failed!

but if i hope output is:

> `<base/atomic/gcc_gnu_x64.hpp>`

The follow macro define can do right thing:

`#define ATOMIC_DETAIL_HEADER(prefix) <ATOMIC_JOIN(prefix, ATOMIC_DETAIL_PLATFORM).hpp>`

Answer (score 1):

A cpp macro cannot build strings this way. It can join tokens to form new tokens, but at every stage it must be a valid token. Your example with angle-brackets works because the bracket characters are distinct tokens whereas the double-quotes cannot exist floating-off like that, and you cannot apply `##` to it.

In most contexts, the compiler will concatenate adjacent string literals, so it may be sufficient to `#stringify` each piece at let the compiler do that.

Answer (score 1):

While luser droog correctly stated why your use of quotes didn't work, he didn't show exactly how the goal can be accomplished. Indeed the `#` operator replaces a parameter by a string literal, i. e. puts quotation marks around the argument. This is slightly complicated by the fact that your token sequence has to be expanded first, so an additional level of macro substitution is needed:

```
#define QUOTED(a)   #a
#define QUOTE(a)    QUOTED(a)
#define ATOMIC_DETAIL_HEADER(prefix) QUOTE(ATOMIC_JOIN(prefix, ATOMIC_DETAIL_PLATFORM).hpp)
```